# How to fit Gumbel distribution?

Tags: r

I want to find a package in R to fit the extreme value distribution
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution with three unknown parameters `mu`, `sigma`, `xi`.

I found two packages that can do the inference for these three parameters based on maximum likelihood estimation.

```r
library(ismev)
gev.fit(data)
```

and

```r
library(extRemes)
fevd(data)
```

the output is estimates of `mu`, `sigma`, and `xi`.

But if I just want to fit distribution with two parameters `mu` and `sigma` (like Gumbel distribution, the parameter `xi=0`). How to apply the above two packages? Or are there any other packages that can do inference for the Gumbel distribution?

Comment: Try writing out the log likelihood in a self-defined function and then using `optim` to find the MLE estimates. If you are unfamiliar with writing your own likelihood equations, [this link](https://www.ime.unicamp.br/~cnaber/optim_1.pdf) provides a pretty good start, and plenty of other resources on SO/google.

Comment: Technically, "find packages to ..." is off-topic for SO (I think this is silly for R but have been [out-argued on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295845/might-is-there-a-package-rather-than-whats-the-best-package-questions-be-ok). I edited your question a little bit so that it's more "how do I solve this problem?" than "what packages are there ...?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `evd` package has 2-parameter `[dpqr]gumbel` functions that you can combine with any general-purpose optimization method (`optim()` is one such possibility, as suggested in the comments, but there are some shortcuts as suggested below).

Load packages, simulate example:

```r
library(evd)
library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(101)
x <- rgumbel(1000, loc = 2, scale = 2.5)
```

Make a more robust wrapper for `dgumbel()` that won't throw an error if we hand it a non-positive `scale` value (there are other ways to deal with this problem, but this one works):

```r
dg <- function(x, loc, scale, log) {
   r <- try(dgumbel(x, loc, scale, log), silent = TRUE)
   if (inherits(r, "try-error")) return(NA)
   return(r)
}
fitdistr(x, dg, start = list(loc = 1, scale = 1))
```

Results seem reasonable:

```r
      loc         scale   
  2.09220866   2.48122956 
 (0.08261121) (0.06102183)
```

If you want more flexibility I would recommend the `bbmle` package (for possibly obvious reasons :-) )

Comment: If you charged anything for you packages or always excellent advice then this would be dangerously close to advertising. Since you don't it's just another opportunity to thank you for your generosity of time and spirit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means. "maximal block" == "maximum likelihood" ?? You can use `MASS::fitdistr()`, the `fitdistrplus` package, or the `bbmle` package to fit a wide range of distributions to data using maximum likelihood.

Comment: That may be a fine method of estimation, but I've never heard of it before (is this question related to yours? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/595004/how-to-compare-the-estimators-obtained-in-the-following-two-ways-which-one-is-b )